# Here Mobile SDK PositionIndicator tilted state

Tags: android, here-api

I'm working with Android Mobile SDK. How can I set Tilt value for default current position indicator (green circle), so when user change tilt for entire map (by doing two fingers swipe), position indicator follows as well.

Or (if it can't be done with default marker), how can I achive it with custom marker resource)? // I can illustrate it by following screens. On second image circle stays the same, instead of transformed into isometric view itself.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a 3d object model and create a [LocalMesh](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-localmesh.html#topic-apiref) + [MapLocalModel](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-maplocalmodel.html) Object to display it in 3d.

Either create a flat rectangle and alter the pitch / yaw / roll according to the camera which may look awkward or use a 3d mesh and to follow the camera pitch / yaw /roll to make it look like there is depth to the object.